# Python do nothing IF empty JSON object

Tags: python, json, okta-api

I am a python noob looking for best practice advice and a resolution to this problem. I am able to successfully pull the data I require from the Okta API which results in the output ***"PRECONDITION FAILED. Errors reported by remote server: Failed to update.  Resource changed on the server."*** thats only half of what I want. I would like to be able to check for that output every 60 minutes and if it doesnt exist do nothing. I thought thats what I was doing in code below in the "start" function but it doesnt seem to behave the way I want it to. How do I store json objects in the variable events or exit the app if the object doesnt appear? Thank you in advance!

```
import requests
import os
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

key = os.environ['OKTA_AUTH']
outcome = 'outcome.result eq "FAILURE"'
event_type = 'eventType eq "application.provision.user.deactivate"'
app_id = 'target.id eq "*******"'
all_params = f'{event_type} and {app_id} and {outcome}'
api_url = f'https://domain.okta.com/api/v1/logs'

last_hour_date_time = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=60)
since = str(last_hour_date_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'))

def auth_okta():
    url = api_url.format()
    print(url)
    params = {
        'filter': all_params,
        'since': since
    }
    response = requests.get(url, params=params,
                        headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 
                        'authorization': key})
    response_json = response.json()
    return response_json

def start():
    for event_data in auth_okta():
        events = event_data['outcome']['reason']
        if not events:
            print('nothing there')
        else:
            print(events)

start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sys.exit() to end all execution.

```
if events == None:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .get command on your event_data:

```
for event_data in auth_okta():
    events = None
    while events is None:
        events = event_data.get("outcome", None).get("reason", None)
        print("Nothing found... waiting")
        time.sleep(3600) #wait one hour
    print(events)
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that my initial structure of the code was creating far too many lists and I ended up restructuring the whole script. I also took some advice from greg.

```
import requests
import sys
import os
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

key = os.environ['OKTA_AUTH']
outcome = 'outcome.result eq "FAILURE"'
event_type = 'eventType eq "application.provision.user.deactivate"'
target_type = 'target.type eq "User"'
app_id = 'target.id eq "APP-ID-HERE"'
all_params = f'{event_type} and {target_type} and {app_id} and {outcome}'
api_url = f'https://DOMAIN.okta.com/api/v1/logs'
slack_url = "SLACK WEBHOOK URL"
last_hour_date_time = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=1)
since = str(last_hour_date_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'))
unique_set=[]


class Events:
    def okta_auth(self):
        event_list=[]
        url = api_url.format()
        params = {
            'filter': all_params,
            'since': since
        }
        response = requests.get(url, params=params,
                            headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 
                            'authorization': key})
        response_json = response.json()
        for event_data in response_json:
            events = event_data['outcome']['reason']
            targets = event_data['target']
            parse = list(map(lambda x: x['alternateId'], targets))
            target_list=[]
            event_list.append(events)
            target_list.append(parse[1])
            for item in target_list:
                if item not in unique_set:
                    unique_set.append(item)
        if event_list != []:
            self.post_slack()
        else:
            sys.exit(0)

    def post_slack(self):
        url = slack_url.format()
        payload =  "{\"text\": \" Twilio Flex provisioing failure. Please check the following users: \n %s \"}" % '\n'.join(unique_set)        
        requests.post(url, headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, data=payload)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Events().okta_auth()
```